# How to correctly use Datepart( ) in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, date

I have two date fields dd.mm.yyyy with a start and an end date in my attribute table. Now I want only to extract the years from these fields to new fields. So I created another field, and used `year_start_date = DatePart ( "YYYY", [Start_date] )` in the field calculator.

But the result is a complete date (dd.mm.yyyy) more than 100 years ago.

Just to test, I created a new field and added with the function `Now()` the actual date (13.05.2014) and tried again to use `year_start_date = DatePart ( "YYYY", [Start_date] )` and I got "06.07.1905" as a result.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this?
I use ArcGIS 10.2.

Comment: Is your field year_start_date a date field or an integer field?

Comment: All of these fields are date fields, not integer or string.

Comment: There's your problem there, DatePart returns an integer and putting that into a date field is bad.. the date is stored as long date format as seconds from some point (possibly 1905); I'm sure there's more explanation about that available. You need to turn your integer back into a date to put it into a date field, here's something that might help explain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623156/how-to-convert-the-integer-date-format-into-yyyymmdd

Comment: I just tried it. It works. You're great!! Thanks :-)

Comment: Awesome! I'll turn that into an answer to neaten up this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DatePart returns an integer and putting that into a date field is bad.. the date is stored as long date format as seconds from some point (possibly 1905); I'm sure there's more explanation about that available, but's lets just accept that that's the way that it is.

You need to turn your integer back into a date to put it into a date field, here's something that might help explain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623156/how-to-convert-the-integer-date-format-into-yyyymmdd